# Spain entry requirements for US citizen

Tags: spain, covid-19

Sorry if this has been asked already. I was looking at the entry requirements for coming into Spain if you are from the USA and it says you will need to show them your vaccination card. This is from their health ministry website. Am I correct in understand that this is the card that you get when you get the first vaccine shot and nothing needs to be done to it? I am coming in as a student and have my student visa, in case that matters.

Comment: If you received a two-shot vaccine, does the card also reflect the date and vaccine lot numbers for both shots?

Comment: I believe it does. One mine it shows the dates I got both shots and what they were and all of that stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to contact the consulate. They told me that it is the vaccine card that you get when you get your shots. It does not need to be translated or notarized.